# How do i loop through a range and use the replace method for each cell?

Tags: excel, vba, replace, range

Dim z as range

```
 For Each z In Range([C2], Cells(Rows.Count, "C").End(xlUp))
 z.Value = Range("C2").Replace("/****", "", 2)
 Next z
```

I tried doing the above but what it did was it replaced all the cells in the range with the boolean 'True' instead of the edited cell.

[image: data screengrab]

What I need to do here is to remove characters from '/' and beyond, so for example C2 would simply become ABG

Comment: You don't need a loop... call `Range.Replace` on the entire column.

Comment: thanks, I tried but somehow my cells still end up with 'True' :(

Comment: * is wildcard for Excel Replace function and therefore you might be getting unexpected results. Can you post sample of your actual data please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. You don't need a loop, just call `Replace` on the entire column.
2. You only need one wildcard `*`.
3. `xlPart` is more meaningful than `2`.

```
Range("C:C").Replace "/*", "", xlPart
```